# Expressing the state of something that is planned to be executed

Tags: word-choice, grammar

I am searching for the right expression that describe the state of something that is planned to be
For example, I plan to bake a cake, and try to hide that from my kids. How do I ask for a hiding place for my not yet baked cake? With emphasis on the planned activity of baking.

Can I say

> Do you know a hiding place for my to be baked cake?

Or do I say

> Do you know a hiding place for my cake to be baked?

Comment: _yet-to-be-baked_ cake?

Comment: When I saw the title of this question ("the state of something that is planned to be executed"), my mind immediately thought, _"On death row?"_

Comment: The first sentence sounds downright wrong; the second one sounds a bit awkward, but passable in certain contexts. Your best option is using a different construction, as below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A short way to say it would be:

> Where can I hide the cake I will bake?

Answer (score 4):

> Where can I hide the cake once it's baked?
>   Where can I hide the cake I'm going to bake?

I have a feeling there are quite a number of ways of saying this...

Comment: Right on, like, "Where can I hide the cake after it's done?" or, "Where will we hide the cake?"

Comment: But avoid  “Where can I hide the cake when baked?” which might invoke sense 2 of [baked](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/baked)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the expression "in the works" to imply that your cake is not ready yet, but it will be ready soon.

> *in the works.*
>   Fig. being prepared; being planned; being done.

An example sentence is:

"My cake is in the works, but I will need a place to hide it. Do you know of any?"

I just made the expression longer, but *in the works* is an idiomatic way to express "the planned activity of baking".

Answer (score 1):

"Do you know of a hiding place for my future cake?"

This is not as weird as it sounds, really.  We use future to describe our as-yet-unwed spouse and relations, i.e. future husband, future daughter-in-law, etc.

Comment: I think a synonym for "future cake" is _batter_. ;^)